# impedir la repeticion de la tecla presionada largo tiempo

Tags: javascript, html5

Como se puede impedir que se vaya repitiendo la tecla presionada?

es decir que cuando se teclea una tecla solamente tiene que escribirse 1 sola vez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para jquery vale esto:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
 var pulsado = false;
  
    
 $("input").keydown(function(){
   if(pulsado) return false;
   pulsado = true;
    })
     
  .keyup(function(){
   pulsado = false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
manten una tecla pulsada <input type="text" >
```

Comment: funciona 100%, pero necesito en js puro, lo cambiare

Comment: +1 para cambiarlo ... yo no he tenido tiempo saludos

Comment: lo publicare luego